# How to use Dagger with MVP in android

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, dagger-2, dagger

I want develop one application with **Rxjava**, **Dagger**, **Kotin** and **MVP**.
I write below codes but when run application show me `nullPointerExecetpion` error.
I know `nullPointerExeception` for my codes bug, but i try to found my bug i can't it!

**My base fragment codes:**

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment(), BaseView {

    var presenter: BasePresenter<*>? = null

    abstract fun initializeDagger()
    abstract fun initializePresenter()
    abstract var layoutID: Int

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(layoutID, container, false)

        initializeDagger()
        initializePresenter()

        return view

    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        presenter?.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

**HomePresenter code:**

```
class HomeTodayPresenter @Inject constructor(
    val repositoryUseCase: RepositoryUseCase, disposable: CompositeDisposable
) : BasePresenter<HomeTodayView>(disposable) {

    private var todayList = ArrayList<Today>()

    fun onCreate() {
        view?.initRepositoryList(todayList)
        getTodayList()
    }

    fun onTodayRefreshList() {
        getTodayList()
    }

    private fun getTodayList() {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            repositoryUseCase.getAuctionsToday()
                .subscribe({ responseResult ->
                    view?.hideLoader()
                    responseResult?.let { itResponse ->
                        itResponse.res?.let { itRes ->
                            itRes.today?.let { itToday ->
                                if (itToday.size > 0) {
                                    todayList.clear()
                                    todayList.addAll(itToday)
                                    view?.loadRepositoryList()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, { e ->
                    view?.let { itView ->
                        e.message?.let { itErr ->
                            itView.showErrorMessage(itErr)
                        }
                        itView.hideLoader()
                    }
                })
        )
    }
}
```

**Home Fragment code:**

```
class HomeTodayFragment : BaseFragment(), HomeTodayView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var homeTodayPresenter: HomeTodayPresenter
    lateinit var todayAuctionsAdapter: TodayAuctionsAdapter
    lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    private val swipeRefreshListener = SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
        homeTodayPresenter.onTodayRefreshList()
    }

    override fun initRepositoryList(list: ArrayList<Today>) {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        todayAuctionsAdapter = TodayAuctionsAdapter(list)
        requireContext().initRecyclerView(homeFragToday_list, layoutManager, todayAuctionsAdapter)
    }

    override fun loadRepositoryList() {
        todayAuctionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun hideLoader() {
        homeFragToday_loader.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun showErrorMessage(msg: String) {
        Log.e("responseErr", msg)
    }

    override fun initializeDagger() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(requireActivity())
    }

    override fun initializePresenter() {
        super.presenter = homeTodayPresenter
        homeTodayPresenter.view = this
    }

    override var layoutID: Int = R.layout.fragment_home_today

    private lateinit var toolbarTile: TextView
    lateinit var handler: Handler


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        homeTodayPresenter.onCreate()
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        activity?.let {
            toolbarTile = it.findViewById(R.id.homePage_toolbarTitle)
        }
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            //Initialize
            handler = Handler()
            //Set delay
            handler.postDelayed({
                //Set title
                toolbarTile.text = resources.getString(R.string.today)
                toolbarTile.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.green_active, null))
            }, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat error :**

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property homeTodayPresenter has not been initialized
    at com.app.applisttestapp.UI.Home.Fragments.Today.HomeTodayFragment.onCreateView(HomeTodayFragment.kt:69)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2539)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
```

Show me error for this line : `homeTodayPresenter.onCreate()`

How can i fix it?

Comment: You don't have a null pointer, you have an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` because the field `homeTodayPresenter` is not injected properly.

Comment: Is it you `Jake Wharton` from Google? ;)  https://github.com/JakeWharton

Comment: @m0skit0, how can i it? can you help me and send to me code? please my friend because i am amateur

Comment: @HarounHajem, no my friend :) can you help me?

Comment: @Jakewarton Sorry man Dagger is pain, can't help you out. If i could i would <3

Comment: Sorry I'm more a Koin guy, but I'm sure you can look at tutorials for Dagger :)

Comment: @m0skit0 please explain to me the difference between an NPE and an UninitializedPropertyAccessException, other than that one of them occurs when the property is marked lateinit, but wasn't initialized, and therefore it was actually still null.

Comment: @Jakewarton I think you used `AndroidInjection` instead of `AndroidSupportInjection`. And you are passing the Activity instead of the Fragment (`this`).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, thanks dear friend. but can you send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur and really need your help. thanks

Comment: just replace `AndroidInjection.inject(requireActivity())` with `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`